# Adding New Button to Sales_Order_View not pointing to my controller

Tags: php, magento

This my Sales Order View /app/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order

```
/* UPDATE INCLUDED BY DRAGONPAY PAYMENT MODULE - START */
/**
 * This button is added for DragonPay for QUERY API button for manual checking of payment result    
 */
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'dragonpay'){        
        $message = 'Query the Payment Gateway To Check If Any Payments Made?';
        $url = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('dragonpay/adminhtml_dragonpayapi/query/',array('order_id'=>$order->getId()));
        $this->addButton('dragonpayapi_query', array(
                'label'     => '[--DRAGONPAY:Get payment status--]',
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$url}')",
        ));             
}        
/* UPDATE INCLUDED BY DRAGONPAY PAYMENT MODULE - END */
```

This is my Admin dragonpay controller located at

```
app/code/local/Namespace/modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/



       <?php


        /**
         * Admindragonpay Controller
         *
         */
        class PixelPlusOne_Dragonpay_Adminhtml_DragonpayAPIController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
            public function indexAction(){
                    echo "hello";
            }

    }




But when i click the button on my Order View i am not redirected to my controller any help is appreciated
```

This is my Sales Order View

Comment: To stand any chance of getting an answer to your question, please reduce your code to an [mcve].

Comment: Please post your config.xml, So I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Model</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Helper</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <dragonpay>
        <class>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Block</class>
      </dragonpay>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <default>
    <payment>
      <dragonpay>
        <model>dragonpay/standard</model>
        <active>1</active>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>Dragon Pay</title>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      </dragonpay>
    </payment>
  </default>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
              <modules>
                <PixelPlusOne_DragonPay after="Mage_Adminhtml">PixelPlusOne_DragonPay_Adminhtml
                </PixelPlusOne_DragonPay>
              </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <dragonpay>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>PixelPlusOne_DragonPay</module>
          <frontName>dragonpay</frontName>
        </args>
      </dragonpay>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```